# Decrease in algebraic degree on multiplying a real number with a root of unity

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

Let $\omega$ be a $\textbf{root of unity}$ with algebraic degree(degree of its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$) $d_1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $r$ be a $\textbf{real number}$ with algebraic degree $d_2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can $r\omega$ have algebraic degree $= d_3$ strictly less than $d_1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Is there an explicit non-trivial lower bound for $d_3$ in terms of $d_1$ and $d_2$?

Note that if both multiplicands were real numbers then decrease in algebraic degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is possible, example: $a, b = \sqrt{2}$. Similarly, if both multiplicands were roots of unity then decrease in algebraic degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is possible, example: $a, b = i$.

Comment: I misread and thought you wanted $d_3<d_2$. I have a vague recollection of somebody settling that question here, but I couldn't find it :-(

Comment: @IvanNeretin I believe $rw$ still has degree $4$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that would be interesting in its own right.

Comment: Not ruling out the possibility that the question I had in mind is [the one where we collaborated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2257129/11619) :-(

Comment: @nikhil_vyas I thought $\omega=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, so $r\omega=1+i$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$? Maybe I miss something again?

Comment: @awllower you are right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I can accept this if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/8}={1+i\over\sqrt2}$ and $r=\sqrt2$ will do. This gives $d_1=4,\;d_2=2,\;d_3=2<d_1$.

On the other hand, I don't see an easy way to make $d_3<{1\over2}d_1$. Maybe that's the lower bound you are after, though I can't be sure at the moment.

Comment: Yeah $d_3 > cd_1$ for some constant $c$ would suffice for my application.